# Windows CE lockdown

Tags: security, windows-ce, lockdown

My company just began purchasing Windows CE 5 & 7 based devices.  The only application that they need to run is Remote Desktop.  I am looking for solutions to lock them down so our users cannot fiddle with settings or use them to surf the web.

I've already looked into SureLock -- which might work for the handful of CE 5 devices that we have.  But, moving forward, it'll be CE 7 or 2013, and SureLock is, apparently, no longer in active development.

Anyone have any suggestions for locking down Windows CE?  (aka "Kiosk mode")

Thanks!

Comment: Windows CE 5 was released in 2004; it is now [past end of support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle?p1=3100). I hope you didn't get ripped off too badly on those devices.

Comment: Just because MS doesn't support doesn't mean there aren't still uses for it.  And, we got a very sweet deal on those devices.  Also, none of this answers my question.  Thanks.